# Use of strdup() in flex

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer, strdup

I want to send duplicate string to my bison file.

In my flex file I use it like this

```
    "<"     {return strdup(tOPEN);}

    ">"     {return strdup(tCLOSE);}
```

Is this right things to do? 
Or should I use it like below the code.

```
    "<"       { yyval. sval = strdup(yytext); return tOPEN;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  "<"       { yyval. sval = strdup(yytext); return tOPEN;}
```

this is the right way of the using.

Comment: Could you explain why? The answer would be better.